# I'm in an internship and I don't feel comfortable, what should I do?

Tags: internship

So, a little background first. My university requires me to do an obligatory four month internship at the end of my first year of studies. I followed plenty of advice here regarding job interviews and I managed to get an internship in an animation studio, the place is great, there's an amazing athmosphere all around but there's one thing that's making me kinda miserable:

I feel out of place.

How can I put this, I am a pretty reserved guy and I don't want people to consider me as rude or anything because I might have ignored a greeting, I have been here for a little less than a month but I find it hard to connect with my co workers.

Another problem I have is that I am basically doing a programming job all by myself, as an intern, alone for the most part. I feel extremely tired everyday, this is making me advance less and less in the project I'm currently working on. Sometimes I'll just slack for about an hour because my brain simply cannot focus on the task anymore. Is this normal for an intern? this is also my first job, everyday I feel like I shouldn't be doing this, even if I'm curious and I do my best to learn stuff I just feel like something is wrong, as if I have chosen the wrong career path. These thoughts torment me everyday.

I would like to know what do you guys think of this? or if anybody has been in a similar situation, I don't want the rest of my internship to be like this, it is detrimental to my productivity and I don't want to give a bad image of myself.

Comment: Just FYI, if you can edit this and clarify the question to something more specific than "What do you think of this", we could possibly [reopen this](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions) for more answers. See [ask] for more guidance. If you [edit] this post, it goes back into our [community reopen review queue](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/reopen). Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is entirely possible that the organization you are in is not providing the best support for their interns. It is your duty to let them know when you need help and they may, or may not provide it. At least, you would have tried.

Software Engineering is generally, in well functioning organizations, a team effort. Sometimes, you have to go to the team and sometimes the team comes to you.

If placed in a similar situation, I would seek help from your colleagues and provide information on your progress. I would be very explicit about the obstacles you are facing.

It is important for you to keep things in perspective. This is a four-month project, not a long term assignment. This is a learning experience. You will learn what you like, what you don't like. This will help you when it is time for you to find a long term position.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think my best approach for now would be to let my supervisor know about my difficulties

Answer (score 4):

Everyone feels out of place (i'm in a programming placement atm too!)

Just keep asking questions about what you're doing, and it will sort itself out!

Try to interact with your boss/co workers more, and it will help you feel more comfortable with your position!

Internships and placements are VITAL to both your course and development in life - especially if it's your first job!

Computing in general can be quite hard for a student to 'break through', and placement/internships are a great way of learning **real world** computing skills.

Nearly all students feel this way for the first few weeks, but as you learn more/become more confident in your position, it will get **much easier**.

(**Source:** Myself, I'm in the same position as you).